# Laravel9: How to let model's find() work?

Tags: laravel

I have service layer. My codes works in Laravel 5.6. Now I'm rewriting in Laravel 9, it doesn't work anymore.

**UserController**

```
public function getForm($id = null)
{
    ...
    $user = $this->userService->findIdOrNew($id);
```

**UserService**

```
class UserService
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->modelName = "\App\Models\User";
        $this->model = new $this->modelName;
        $this->table = $this->model->getTable();
    }

    private function newModel()
    {
        return new $this->modelName;
    }

    public function findIdOrNew($id = null)
    {
        if(empty($id)){
            $row = new $this->modelName;
        }else{
            $row = $this->model->find($id);
            echo "<pre>", print_r($row, 1), "</pre>";exit;
        }
        return false;        
    }
```

Logic:
If no user id, then new an emtpy user model, return it.
If user id provided, then get the user model, and find the user id.
$this->model only do the new action in __controller.

I have many other functions like this.

```
public function updateById($data, $id)
{
    $row = $this->model->find($id);
    $row->email = $data['email'];
    $row->name = $data['name'];
    ...

public function getRows($data = array(), $debug = 0)
{
    $query = $this->model->query();

    if(!empty($data['filter_ids'])){
        $query->whereIn('id', $data['filter_ids']);
    }

    if(!empty($data['filter_name'])){
        $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

        $query->where(function ($query) use($words) {
            $query->orWhere(function ($query2) use($words) {
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $query2->where('name', 'like', "%{$word}%");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

In this way, I don't use User::find(1), I don't need to say which model I want in functions. Just write it once in __contructor().

It really works in my laravel 5.6. Now it returns empty. No error message.

```
public function findIdOrNew($id = null)
{
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE ^E_DEPRECATED);
    
    $row = $this->model->find($id);
    echo "<pre>", print_r($row, 1), "</pre>";exit;
```

I should get:

```
App\Models\User Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => email
            [2] => password
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => password
            [1] => remember_token
        )

    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [table:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50
            [rcode] => 1971836358
            [name] => ooxxooxx
    ...
```

Now just a white page. What did I missed ?

I deleted all logs, restart apache server, then reload the page.

**Apache/logs/laraocadmin9.test-access.log**
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2022:14:39:46 +0800] "GET /en/admin/system/user/users/49/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 11
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2022:14:39:48 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -

**Apache/logs/laraocadmin9.test-error.log**
(empty)

**Apache/logs/access.log**
(empty)

**Apache/logs/error.log**
[Thu Jun 16 14:38:09.392250 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 40028:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 16 14:38:09.393249 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 40028:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Mar 16 2022 11:26:15
[Thu Jun 16 14:38:09.406444 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 40028:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 20972
[Thu Jun 16 14:38:10.096179 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20972:tid 432] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

**Laravel storage\logs**
only a file name .gitnore

Comment: Show errors from error log.

Comment: I updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it still works. The user id I passed was wrong. I had two different projects. one is

```
$this->getForm('edit', $id)
$this->getForm('create', $id)
function getForm($action, $id=null)
```

another is

```
$this->getForm($id)
$this->getForm($id)
function getForm($id=null)
```

I got mixed up, I passed 'edit' to getForm($id)